# Drive API App OAuth Permissions Not Updating

Tags: go, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I am working on a Golang service that will connect to Google Drive and download a file. The issue is that no matter how I update the projects permissions, when I run application and go to the browser window to OAuth, it only shows the `metadata` permissions needing granted when have granted more so that I can download files.

Here are the steps I've taken for the service:

1. I have created a project in Google Developer Console.
2. In that project I have enabled and updated Google Drive permissions to the capture all `auth/drive` permission (I have also tried granting all and only some granular).
3. I create the Golang service from this example: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/go
4. I run the Golang app which prompts me to open a URL in browser to OAuth authenticate.
5. I open link in browser, auth with my app-owner gmail account and *every single time no matter what I do* this is the only OAuth scope that shows:

[image]

If I use the [Drive API Explorer to perform the file download](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) it shows that I need these permissions:

[image]

When i click "Execute" in the explorer the OAuth popup shows all the permissions I would expect for my app and works correctly:

[image]

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Could this be because the app is an "internal" app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the [Golang Quick-Start boilerplate code](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/go) that I used to scaffold the application.

This line was overriding the permission settings I was explicitly setting in console.

```golang
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved token.json.
    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, drive.DriveMetadataReadonlyScope)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
```

fixed when changed to:

```golang
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved token.json.
    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, drive.DriveScope)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
```